# Why GTM -> GA4 removes "0x" from a string?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Custom GTM (google tag manager) event tries to send a string like `"0x8"` to GA4 (Google Analytics 4) property. In the Preview I can clearly see it's represented like `"0x8"`.

However, on the GA side the `"0x"` is no longer there, and the dimension value is just `"8"`.

Where this happens and how to prevent it (other than somehow encode the string somehow). I'd expected dimension strings to arrive to GA4 intact, without fix-ups like this.

Answer (score 0):

`0x` is commonly used as a prefix for hexadecimal numbers, so it seems that GA parses the expression as such.

You could try submitting a value such as `"0xA"` to check whether this is interpreted as `"10"`, which would confirm the theory.

Comment: Yes, this came to mind, but the question is whether it can be somehow prevented?

Comment: [Simo Ahava encountered a similar issue with the CID](https://www.simoahava.com/gtmtips/write-client-id-other-gtag-fields-datalayer/#create-a-new-google-analytics-4-event-tag) and solved it by appending a dot to the value to force GA to treat it as a string. Not sure if this is feasible in your case.

Comment: Yes, that is what I called 'encoding' in my question and hoped to fix without artificial prefixes/suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

One quick fix for this is to add some postfix to the values, after which GA4 does not convert strings to numbers. This can be done in the event parameter value e.g. like:

`{{ JS some var }}=`

The particular postfix depends on what is easier to remove. While the prefix would do the same, the general wisdom when dealing with values indexed in the database is to minimize the number of same-prefixed values.

It remains unclear whether this behavior of GA will be fixed or is for some reason beneficial.

As pointed out in the comments to another answer, this blog explains the problem in more detail: https://www.simoahava.com/gtmtips/write-client-id-other-gtag-fields-datalayer/#create-a-new-google-analytics-4-event-tag